# How to create a nice mac osx dmg with a script in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, dmg

I’ve finish the development of one of my mac osx app and I would like to create a dmg automatically with a script. Since I will have to realize some automatic release in the future I can’t use the manual way. But this thing drives me crazy because I’ve been working on it for many days now and I all I get is random success (worst thing ever).

Since there is no many information about it on the web it could help some people who tries to do the same thing.

My problem is I created a bash script to build my dmg and I use an apple script to make it nice. BUT sometimes I manage to get the perfect dmg and then, the second build is totally bad, like little windows size or no more background and I get the following error:

*execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t get disk « My App ». (-1728)*

And here is the "Applescript" part I'm using in my script:

```
echo '
tell application "Finder"
tell disk "'${VOL_NAME}'"
open
set current view of container window to icon view
set toolbar visible of container window to false
set statusbar visible of container window to false
set the bounds of container window to {400, 100, 920, 370} 
set viewOptions to the icon view options of container window
set arrangement of viewOptions to not arranged
set icon size of viewOptions to 72
set background picture of viewOptions to file ".background:Background.png"
set position of item "'${APP_NAME}'.app" of container window to {160, 105}
set position of item "Applications" of container window to {360, 105}
close
update without registering applications
delay 2
end tell
end tell
' | osascript
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the AppleScript as .scpt file, and then running the osascript on that?  I use that a lot with LaunchAgent, and it never fails.

Comment: Thanks @CraigSmith for your help. I will try this but I found an other solution: I run the bash script with the lines above, I take the .DS_Store in the dmg, then I comment the AppleScript in my bash script and read only the .DS_Store